# How do I repeat an iteration across a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Very new to Python, I have a large data frame and I am trying to display 5 lines of the raw data each time the user input = "yes" I want the data to progress by 5 lines each time the user inputs yes.

I have tried both using .iloc and .iterrows but I can't figure out how to get the output to progress beyond the rows I defined in iloc.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
def raw_data(df):
    """
    Asks user if they want to see 5 lines of raw data.
    Then returns 5 lines of raw data if user inputs `yes`. Iterates until user response with a `no`
    """

    data = df 
    while True:
        answer = input('Would you like to see 5 lines of raw data? Enter yes or no: ')
        if answer.lower() == 'yes':
            print(data.iloc[:5])
            data += 5
        else:
            break
```

I was trying to use `data += 5` to progress but it triggers "ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq."

I'm stumped on which direction to go in next. 
Help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.iloc` takes as first index the row indices and as a second one the columns indices you want to show.

So, if you want to show just a chunk of 5 rows and all columns use:

```py
df.iloc[idx:idx+5, :]
```

Full example:

```py
def raw_data(df):
    """
    Asks user if they want to see 5 lines of raw data.
    Then returns 5 lines of raw data if user inputs `yes`. Iterates until user response with a `no`
    """

    idx = 0
    while True:
        answer = input('Would you like to see 5 lines of raw data? Enter yes or no: ')
        if answer.lower() == 'yes':
            print(df.iloc[idx:idx+5, :])
            idx += 5
        else:
            break
```

See also https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Answer (score 0):

This works for me if I want five rows, then five more rows, and on...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/python/api.csv')

def raw_data(df):
    """
    Asks user if they want to see 5 lines of raw data.
    Then returns 5 lines of raw data if user inputs `yes`. Iterates until user response with a `no`
    """
    position = 5
    data = df 
    while True:
        answer = input('Would you like to see 5 lines of raw data? Enter yes/y or no/n: ')
        if (answer.lower() == 'yes') | (answer.lower() == 'y'):
            print(data.iloc[position-5:position])
            position += 5
        else:
            break

raw_data(df)
```